# A few problems using longtable

Tags: tikz-pgf, longtable

I am quite new to LaTeX but I love its typographic clearness and I'm using it to create pdf for some geometric drawings, nothing involved with scientific writing.

Now I'm working with some Lissajous figures and I want some pages with a lot of Lissajous figures exploring different parameters. For drawing I'm using the TikZ package. I generate all `.tex` code with a Python script.

If you have better solutions than `longtable` please advice about them, I'm only a new user.

First of all I want automatic spacing: if I try to put 20 figures on one row the table exceeds the page and I have to manually change the `[scale=0.2]` parameter in `\begin{tikzpicture}`. This is quite annoying.

Then I want the table not to be centered but to fill all the page and I don't know how to do it. This screenshot explain better, i hope:

[image]

This is my TeX code (only what I think is the important part):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \bf{\Huge{ Lissajous figures \\ }}
\end{center}

\begin{longtable}{llllllllllllllllllll}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
\draw (0.0,0.0) -- (0.32,0.32);
\draw (0.32,0.32) -- (0.61,0.61);
...
\draw (-0.61,-0.61) -- (-0.32,-0.32);
\draw (-0.32,-0.32) -- (0.0,0.0);
\end{tikzpicture}

&
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
\draw (0.0,0.16) -- (0.32,0.47);
\draw (0.32,0.47) -- (0.61,0.73);
...
\draw (-0.61,-0.47) -- (-0.32,-0.16);
\draw (-0.32,-0.16) -- (0.0,0.16);
\end{tikzpicture}



\\
\hfill
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are aware that `longtable` is for multi-page tables, not for very wide tables? You can scale something to a specific width using `\resizebox{<width>}{!}{<content>}`, but placing a `longtable` or any other multi-page element doesn't work here. Please clarify if you really need multi-page tables.

Comment: thank you! no i didn't know that. tabular could be a good alternative?

Comment: TikZ itself provides a `\matrix` command, so you could do everything inside TikZ. Otherwise use `tabular`.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest defining a macro like so:`\def\tkzscl{0.2}` and then replace each `scale=0.2` by `scale=tkzscl`. That way, changing one thing will cause all the scales to change...

Comment: Does the `sidewaystable` environment from the [`rotating`](http://ctan.org/pkg/rotating) package help with part of your problem?

Comment: @Seamus Would you try and suggest a real answer with `sidewaystable`?

Comment: @Seamus Did you see egregs comment above?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how you generated your diagrams, so I've replaced them with little blocks. I've used the `rotating` package to provide the `sidewaystable` environment which makes – surprise surprise – a sideways table!

The little blocks have their top left corner chopped off, so you can see that they are displaying sideways. `sidewaystable` will normally float to its own page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\newcommand\block{\rule{2em}{1em}\llap{\rule{1em}{2em}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
  \caption{A sideways table of blocks}
  \begin{tabular}{*{20}{l}}
    \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & Ten    & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & Twenty \\
    \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block \\
    \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block \\
    \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block \\
    \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block \\
    \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block \\
    \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block \\
    \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block \\
    \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block & \block
  \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image: big picture]

And here's a detail from the same file:

[image: detail]